# How to rerun a failing job automatically in talend?

Tags: talend

I am new to talend (less than a month)  i hope can get some help.

I am testing a job that migrate a huge amount of data from an oracle database into salesfroce, the job works fine but sometimes due to some temporary issues with the databases, the job failed.

Is there any way to rerun the job in case of failure automatically after some time (ex: when the connection fails, do a retry 10 minute after) ? i searched the internet  but i did find get any structured solutions, i am really stuck with this problem.

Is this achievable in talend ? if so, what are the component to use and and in which order  ? 
thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you triggering the job? Have you scheduled the job in TAC or scheduled in Windows Scheduler?

Comment: are there specific errors that would like to re-try after? or due to any error you want to re-run?  Also, does your code keep track of where it is at in the process?  is it and all our one batch attempt that rolls back the entire process/transaction or does it commit in smaller batches?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the job status in the table, append the logic(fail or succeed) for every job. Like, Main job -- > on subjob ok -- > connect to some tfixedflowinput with the fields Jobname, Success flag ..

else Main job -- > on subjob error --> connect to some tfixedflowinput with the fields Jobname, failed flag ..

After the jobs loading process is done, schedule the failed jobs to run again by taking the failed jobs data from job status table. (Use tdbxxinput(stats table), tflowtoiterate, context variables, trunjob components to run over failed jobs dynamically)